# Set NSArray as a property of custom class

Tags: properties, nsarray, custom-controls, xcode9.3, ios11.3

I have created one sub class / custom class of `UIView`

Here is `MultiColorView.h` file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MultiColorView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *colors; // default is nil
@end
```

Here is `MultiColorView.m` file

```
#import "MultiColorView.h"

@implementation MultiColorView

- (instancetype)initWithColors:(NSArray *)colors {

     self = [super init];

     self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
     self.clipsToBounds = TRUE;

     CGFloat yOrigin = 0;
     CGFloat heightStipe = self.frame.size.height/colors.count;

     for (int i=0; i<colors.count; i++) {

         UILabel *lblStripe = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yOrigin, self.frame.size.width, heightStipe)];
         lblStripe.backgroundColor = (UIColor *)[colors objectAtIndex:i];
         lblStripe.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
         [self addSubview:lblStripe];

         yOrigin = yOrigin + heightStipe;
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)setColors:(NSArray *)colors {

     self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
     self.clipsToBounds = TRUE;

     CGFloat yOrigin = 0;
     CGFloat heightStipe = self.frame.size.height/colors.count;

     for (int i=0; i<colors.count; i++) {

         UILabel *lblStripe = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yOrigin, self.frame.size.width, heightStipe)];
         lblStripe.backgroundColor = (UIColor *)[colors objectAtIndex:i];
         lblStripe.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
        [self addSubview:lblStripe];

         yOrigin = yOrigin + heightStipe;
    }
}

@end
```

Now if I use like :

Create property wherever you need.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MultiColorView *coloredView;
```

Set colours

```
NSArray *arrColors = @[[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor blackColor]];
self.coloredView.colors = arrColors;  // Crash here
```

Then app is crashing with reason :

> [MultiColorView setColors:] : Unrecognized selector sent by instance.

But if I use like :

```
MultiColorView *view2 = [[MultiColorView alloc] initWithColors:arrColors];
view2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

Then it is working fine. Please suggest what's wrong in code.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you redeclare `MultiColorView` in MultiColorView.m? Is the error "[UIView setColors:]: Unrecognized selector sent to instance …"?

Comment: No I didn't redeclare.

Comment: What is `@interface MultiColorView : UIView` doing in MultiColorView.m? Post real code and errors please. What is the class of the view in IB?